# MY SQL running very slow due to `Order by` & `Limit`

Tags: mysql, performance

I have a performance issue with the query below on MYSQL. The below query has 5 tables involved. When I apply the `order by` and `limit`, the results are retrieved in 0.3 secs. But without the `order by` and `limit`, I was able to get the results in 0.01 secs. I am tired changing the query but that did not work. Could someone please help me with this query so I can get the results in desired time (<0.3 secs).

```
Below are the details.

m_todos = 286579 (records)
m_pat = 214858 (records)
users = 119 (records)
m_programs = 26 (records)
role = 4 (records)


SELECT  *
    FROM (
        SELECT  t.*,
                mp.name as A_name,
                u.first_name, u.last_name,
                p.first, p.last, p.zone, p.language,p.handling,
                r.name,
                u2.first_name AS created_first_name,
                u2.last_name AS created_last_name
            FROM  m_todos t
            INNER JOIN  role r  ON t.role_id=r.id
            INNER JOIN  m_pat p  ON t.patient_id = p.id
            LEFT JOIN  users u2  ON t.created_id=u2.id
            LEFT JOIN  m_programs mp  ON t.prog_id=mp.id
            LEFT JOIN  users u  ON t.user_id=u.id
            WHERE  t.role_id !='9'
              AND  t.completed = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' 
         ) C
    ORDER BY  priority DESC, due ASC
    LIMIT  0,10
```

Comment: Please provide the execution plan for this query - or at the very lest the indexes on the tables.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the outer `SELECT`; move the `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` in.

Indexes:

```
t:  (completed)
t:  (priority, due)
```

I assume `priority` and `due` are in `t`??  Please be explicit in the query.  It could make a huge difference.

If the following works, it should speed things up a lot:  Start by finding the `t.id` *without* all the `JOINs`:

```
SELECT id
    FROM m_todos
    WHERE  role_id !='9'
      AND  completed = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' 
    ORDER BY priority DESC, due DESC
    LIMIT 10
```

That will benefit from this covering composite index:

```
INDEX(completed, role_id, priority, due, id)
```

Debug that.  Then use it in the rest:

```
SELECT t.*, the-other-stuff
    FROM ( that-query ) AS t1
    JOIN m_todos AS t  USING(id)
    then-the-rest-of-the-JOINs
    ORDER BY  priority DESC, due ASC   -- yes, again
```

If you don't need all of `t.*`, it may be beneficial to spell out the actual columns needed.

The reason for this to run much faster is that the 10 rows are found efficiently by looking only at the one table.  The original code was shoveling around a lot more rows than 10 and they included all the columns of `t`, plus columns from the other tables.

My version does only 10 lookups for all the extra stuff.